# Multiple delimiters with arrays

Tags: php

I’m creating a multiple dropdown populated by a database that sometimes will have a value pre-selected.  The table it pulls from has one or more customers separated by a comma.

Example: *“John Doe”* may be one entry and *“Jane Smith, John Doe, Guy Inc.”* and another like  *“Jane Smith, Tom Jones,”* may be next.

To generate a list of distinct options, I use this code:

```
<?php

$result2 = "SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustomerTracker WHERE Customer NOT IN ('', '---< Select Customer >---', 'Left Blank')";
$rs2 = odbc_exec($conncmse,$result2);
$CustomerData0 = '';

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs2)) {
    $Customer0 = $row['Customer'];
    foreach (explode(',', $Customer0) as $Customer) {
        $CustomerData0 .= "<option>" . trim($Customer, " ") . "</option>";
    }
}

$CustomerData = implode('</option><option>',array_unique(explode('</option><option>', $CustomerData0)));

echo $CustomerData;

echo '<select name="Select1" multiple="multiple">';
echo $CustomerData;
echo '</select>';
```

It works fine but if I want to have a pre-selected customer, I came up with this:

```
$SelectedCustomer = "John Doe";

$result2 = "SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM CustomerTracker WHERE Customer NOT IN ('', '---< Select Customer >---', 'Left Blank')";
$rs2 = odbc_exec($conncmse,$result2);
$CustomerData0 = '';
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs2)) {
    $Customer0 = $row['Customer'];
    foreach (explode(',', $Customer0) as $Customer) {
        if(strpos($SelectedCustomer, $Customer) !== false) {
            $CustomerData0 .= "<option selected='selected'>" . trim($Customer, " ") . "</option>";$SelectedCustomer = "";
        }
        else {
            $CustomerData0 .= "<option>" . trim($Customer, " ") . "</option>";
        }
     }
}

$CustomerData = implode("</option><option>",array_unique(explode("</option><option>",  $CustomerData0)));

?>
```

The problem I’m having is that I can only use on delimiter, `</option><option>`, so I get a duplicate of the selected customer. What I really need is a way to have multiple delimiters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having a bit of trouble understanding the question at first, but then took a close look and saw what you are doing. I think you're over complicating it.

```
$selectedCustomer = "John Doe";
$customers = array();
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs2)) {
    //get rid of trailing comma
    $customersString = rtrim($row['Customer'],',');
    //first populate an array with all the customers.
    foreach(explode(',', $customersString) as $customer)
        $customers[] = $customer; 
}
//now eliminate duplicates
$customers= array_unique($customers);
//now create the string with options
foreach($customers as $customer)
{
   $selected = trim($customer) == $selectedCustomer ? 'selected="selected" ': '';
   $CustomerData = '<option '.$selected.'>'.$customer.'</option>';
}

?>
```

this way you're getting the customers first then putting in the markup instead of trying to implode/explode on it in a very confusing way. Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying to get my head around it too - think you nailed it.

Comment: @strat, yeah it took me a while to figure out what his ultimate goal was. Sometimes implode/explode are more confusing than helpful when trying to mix it with markup.